# Vb.net Not Printing,

Tags: vb.net

im trying to print a panel, The problem is its just showing the "Printing" but dont actually print

```
 Private bmp As Bitmap
    Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        bmp = New Bitmap(rec.Width, rec.Height)
        Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        rec.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rec.ClientRectangle)
        G.Dispose()

        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

ive tried different kind of method

Answer (score 1):

```vb
PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
```

```vb
Private Sub PrintDocument2_PrintPage(...) Handles PrintDocument2.PrintPage
```

You have two different `PrintDocument` objects there. You never tell one to print and you never print anything with the other.